# How to fill a (embedded) PDF form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I have a PDF file that I can embed (or load by other means) in an HTML page. The PDF contains a form that can be filled. I have extracted field names using `pdftk`. Here is part of the pdftk output:

```
FieldType: Text
FieldName: Date
FieldFlags: 8388608
FieldJustification: Center
FieldMaxLength: 10
---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: version
FieldFlags: 29360128
FieldJustification: Left
FieldMaxLength: 2
```

Now I need to access the form from the JS and fill in those values. I tried [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) but it doesn't seem to provide any options to fill the form.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to Java or server-side processing?

Comment: If you are displaying the PDF using the embed or object tag, you won't be able to push data into the form in any predictable way. There just isn't enough consistency between the browsers in the way they support PDF. If you can force the users to download and open the PDF in Adobe Reader or Acrobat, then there are client side solutions for the desktop versions but then you still have the problem on mobile. The best solution is to process the form on the server and "flatten" it prior to sending it to the client... sorry for the bad news.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of... i'm using pdftk in the mean time. i guess i'll have to stick with it for now

Comment: pdftk will let you add data to the form but depending on the viewer that the resulting PDF gets opened in, the data may or may not display. From what I understand, pdftk does not create field "appearances" which ar ethe visual representation on the page of the field value in the form. Unlike HTML, in PDF these are separate things. You can make the viewer more likely to display the data if you set the "NeedAppearances" property to true. It's a flag specifying whether to construct appearance streams and appearance dictionaries for all widget annotations in the document.

Comment: pdftk can also flatten the pdf before sending it to client

Comment: Yes... it can. But it can't generate appearances based on field properties reliably. For example, if you have a numeric field that has a format script that adds commas, decimals, and currency signs, pdftk won't know about it so it won't know what the field should *look* like, just what it's value is. Same for calculated fields. pdftk *will* work... but only when yo know enough about the form to compensate for what it doesn't do automatically. It makes for a lot of unnecessary custom form handling.